# How do I read from an input file after passing the ifstream object to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

as the title suggests, I am having a problem with not being able to read from an input file after passing the ifstream object to a class function. Basically I'm trying to sort a list of numbers using a heap ADT implemented with an array.

```
int main() {
   ifstream infile("input.txt");
   HeapSort* heap = new HeapSort(20); // creates a heap (array) with size 20
   heap->buildHeap(&infile);

   return 0;
}

void HeapSort::buildHeap(ifstream* infile) {
    int data;
    while (infile >> data) {cout << data << endl;}
    infile->close();
}
```

the error occurs in the conditional of the while loop inside buildHeap. The compiler can't recognize the operator ">>" between an 'int' and an 'ifstream' object. However, strangely enough, if I write that same while loop inside main(), it'll work just fine. Also of note is that if I remove the while loop, the compiler returns no errors. Meaning, simply the act of passing the ifstream object from main to buildHeap is OK.

Please avoid suggesting alternative ways of achieving this. I was asked to not use any special fstream functions like eof(). I can only use the ">>" operator to read from the desired file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to a stream, so you need to dereference it:

`while (*infile >> data)`

If you want your code to look like what you say you did in `main`, then you pass a reference:

```
heap->buildHeap(infile);
//...
void HeapSort::buildHeap(ifstream& infile) 
{
    int data;
    while (infile >> data) { ... }
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much.

Comment: So the * notation can be used to reference and dereference, eh? Never knew that. Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: The `*` notation is required, since `operator >>` is expecting an object, not a pointer on the left side.  To get the object, you must dereference the pointer.

Comment: Ah, of course, I understand now. I guess I'm too accustomed to Java where almost everything is passed by reference anyway

Comment: @MannyKim, the dereference operator (`*`) can be used to _get the object at a specified address_ (i.e. a pointer). For getting the address of an object (e.g. `int n = 16`) we use the operator with the same name `&` like `&n`) which can be read as _the address of `n`_.

Comment: Also, in C++, you don't need `new` to create your objects, unlike Java.  `HeapSort heap(20);` is all you need.  Using `new` is not such an innocent operator in C++,  it creates a memory leak if you don't call `delete`.

Comment: Thank you @Victor, I already knew about the technicality of the * and & notations. It's in the implementation where it gets a little tricky for me.

Comment: @Paul, yes I'm aware of that and I do have a destructor implemented. I was asked to do it this way for the exercise :-)